# Open URL command from Linux to Windows in Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, url

I have a Linux PC (running Ubuntu) and a Windows 7 PC, and they are connected to the same network.
I want to write a script in Python from the Linux PC that "tells" the Windows PC to open a specific URL.
I know the command in windows is e.g. "start www.google.com", so I think I have to somehow send this command from the Linux to the Windows PC using a Python script.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: There is an infinite number of "solutions" to this problem. You have to be much more specific about your goal, environment, constraints, etc. And why, except for fun, would you like to do this in the first place ?

Comment: I just need one solution, preferably a simple one. I'm not doing this for fun, I'm making an automated test environment and I need this script. 
My goal is to write a python script from the linux PC that tells the Windows PC to open URL. Both PCs are connected to the same network and workgroup. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how the PC's connected, LAN, WAN, Bluetooth? I assume they use a LAN. In this case you can use a socket library to send data from one PC to another.
The Linux will be a client and Win7 will be a server, check this link for example: [Server/Client implementation](http://www.dscripts.net/2010/06/18/how-to-create-a-client-server-socket-connection-in-python/)

Comment: The PCs are connected via LAN, but I don't want the windows PC to run any program. For example, in order to turn off the Windows PC remotely, I use the following command in Python running in the Linux PC:
os.system(net rpc shutdown -I IPADDRESS -U USERNAME%PASSWORD)
The windows PC doesn't run any program to wait for connection, so I want something similar for opening a URL.